# Terms adding twice to 2d Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

0

Context: I am trying to shuffle a 2D arraylist randomly.

For example, if I have the 2d arraylist below (which can be as long in either direction), I want to move all like values together according to an input index (e.g. move all b's to the beginning of their respective array).

```
[[a,b,c]                               [[b,c,a]

,[a,b,c]                ==>            ,[b,c,a]

,[a,b,c]]                              ,[b,c,a]]
```

I was using the method with two data structures. Adding the data to the new data structure and deleting it from the old data structure until all vertical groups have been shuffled.

My first attempt I shuffled the order of the order of the arrays, instead of their contents.

I decided to try this with just one set of data to the new data structure first but it adds the terms to all arrays, despite not even running the line of code that many times.

for examples if each of the 'b's above had a value of 1,2,3 instead of outputting [1][2][3], it outputs [1,2,3][1,2,3][1,2,3]. I have tested the output at each line of code, it goes to plan until `terms2shuffled.get(k).add(intermediateTerms.get(k).get(j));`

My code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> intermediateTerms = new ArrayList<>();
           terms2shuffled = new ArrayList<>();
           
           ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList();
           for(int i = 0;i<columnNumber;i++){
               terms2shuffled.add(temp);
           }
           
           intermediateTerms=terms2;            
           
           int length = intermediateTerms.get(0).size();
               int j = random.nextInt(length);
               for(int k = 0; k<numColumns;k++){
                   System.out.println(intermediateTerms.get(k).get(j));
                   terms2shuffled.get(k).add(intermediateTerms.get(k).get(j));
                   System.out.println(terms2shuffled);

                   //intermediateTerms.remove(j);
```

(where wordsNumber == NO. of rows NumColumns == NO. of columns)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why 'add' and not something like `Collections.swap(indexA, indexB)`?

Comment: Can you post a [mre]? Where does `terms2` come from? What values does it contain at that point and in which order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code lines:

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0;i<columnNumber;i++){
    terms2shuffled.add(temp);
}
```

...add the same `ArrayList` instance for every row, which means that the following line:

```
terms2shuffled.get(k).add(intermediateTerms.get(k).get(j));
```

...will modify that single instance (because `terms2shuffled.get(k)` will always give you `temp`), which should explain why:

> it adds the terms to all arrays

Instead you can try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++) {
    terms2shuffled.add(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

in order to have a separate `List` instance for each row.

---

In the following code:

```
intermediateTerms=terms2;
```

...I am assuming that `terms2` is the original two-dimensional list, so I should note here that by modifying the `intermediateTerms` later on, you are actually also modifying the `terms2` list because they both point to the same instance. If you don't want to modify the original list then you should create a *deep copy* of it and then assign the deep copy to `intermediateTerms`. Since `terms2` is two dimensional, a simple `terms2.clone();` will not be enough.

---

The following `for`-loop declaration:

```
for (int k = 0; k < numColumns; k++)
```

uses `k` as the index of columns, but then in the body of the loop you use `k` to get the *row* in the two dimensional `List`. Since your two dimensional `List` is square, then it shouldn't matter at all. I am just noting this. As far as I understant, this is probably not stopping someone to interpret the rows as columns and the columns as rows, so I am assuming the simplest case here and that's why I am noting this.

---

> if I have the 2d arraylist below (which can be as long in either direction), I want to move all like values together according to an input index (e.g. move all b's to the beginning of their respective array).

In your code given, you seem to do only one operation (ie move a single column in each row, instead of moving multiple columns in each row). Instead you are probably looking to repeat the process for a number of times, like so (in pseudocode):

```
deep copy all values from terms2 to the result list.
for each column (named 'c') repeat:
    generate a random column (named 'r') to change its location in each row.
    for each row (in the resulting list) repeat:
        swap column 'c' for 'r' in the row.
```

But this also seems not enough, because you will only shuffle in a per-line basis, which means that an element from the second row for example will always remain in the second row. Even if after that you shuffle the rows, then still some elements will never leave their row. Instead you may want to shuffle in a per-cell basis (such an example logic and code follows, immediately later, in this post).

---

> I am trying to shuffle a 2D arraylist randomly.

One way to randomize all values in the two dimensional `List` (in a per-cell basis) is to:

1. Collapse the two-dimentional `List` to single dimension.
2. Shuffle in single dimension.
3. Re-create the dimensions from the shuffled single dimension `List`.

For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class ListUtils {
    
    public static <T> void collapseFrom2D(final List<? extends List<T>> inputList2D,
                                          final List<T> outputList1D) {
        inputList2D.forEach(outputList1D::addAll);
    }
    
    public static <T> void setAll(final Iterator<T> inputIter,
                                  final ListIterator<T> outputIter,
                                  final long limit) {
        for (long i = 0; outputIter.hasNext() && inputIter.hasNext() && i < limit; ++i) {
            outputIter.next();
            outputIter.set(inputIter.next());
        }
    }
    
    public static <T> void setAll(final Iterator<T> inputIter,
                                  final ListIterator<T> outputIter) {
        setAll(inputIter, outputIter, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    
    public static <T> void expandTo2D(final Iterator<T> inputValuesIter,
                                      final List<? extends List<T>> outputList2D) {
        final Iterator<? extends List<T>> outputIter = outputList2D.iterator();
        while (outputIter.hasNext())
            setAll(inputValuesIter, outputIter.next().listIterator());
    }
    
    public static <T> void expandTo2D(final List<T> inputList1D,
                                      final List<? extends List<T>> outputList2D) {
        expandTo2D(inputList1D.iterator(), outputList2D);
    }
    
    public static <T> void shuffle2D(final List<? extends List<T>> list) {
        final ArrayList<T> singleDimension = new ArrayList<>();
        collapseFrom2D(list, singleDimension);
        Collections.shuffle(singleDimension);
        expandTo2D(singleDimension, list);
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ArrayList<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
        list.add(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5, 6));
        list.add(Collections.emptyList());
        list.add(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));
        System.out.println("Before: " + list);
        shuffle2D(list);
        System.out.println("After: " + list);
    }
}
```

Which, as far as I understand, can be generalized for `n`-dimensional lists or arrays.

The example code given above does not have to run on a square `List`. It can work for non-rectangular `List`s too.